Verify Amazon CodeCatalyst space
When I am trying to open code catalyst in AWS. I am getting these error

Paste the verification token from Amazon Code Catalyst to verify this AWS account. You can remove this AWS account at any time. Adding an AWS account is required in order to create a space in Amazon Code Catalyst.
What is the verification token and where can we get these token?

I don't know how to find the token. I want to create a repository in code commit and one of my friend told me to create a code catalyst first. So, i want to create a code catalyst how to get the token?

The documentation seems to be pretty clear. There are multiple ways to generate and view the token.
If you've already generated one, using the CLI you can use aws codecatalyst list-access-tokens. If you haven't generated one yet, follow the documentation to generate one first.
